# Convert Desktop App to Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms, vb6-migration

At work, we're currently discussing the eventuality that our product needs to be a web application, mostly due to ease of distribution (e.g. getting servers set up by the IT departments of our customers).

Our desktop application is heavily reliant on user input, it has lots of forms and hundreds of controls which are shown and hidden based on others.

My question is, is there a NICE/EASY way - without having to remodel the entire product, which is our current solution - to make this easy for web development?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That totally depends on how your current product is set up. It it uses the MVC pattern (or other compatible) it should be fairly easy. If you've been working with Smart UI's then you will have to do a lot of work.

Comment: It was originally developed in the 90's in VB6. The application has been iterated on since then and thus isn't really MVC ready.

Answer (score 1):

If ease of distribution is the primary concern then maybe using a Windows Forms ClickOnce might be a viable option as you can publish your application on a webpage and users can run the application from that webpage, but it runs as a local windows forms application - and if you don't need to make any changes to the local registry or other elevated rights operations then all you need on that machine is the correct .NET Framework for it to run.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't really an option. It needs to be a web application.